# Programmatic row selection in a p-table using selectionMode 'multiple'

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I have a PrimeNG v12.2 `p-table` component abbreviated as follows:

```html
<p-table
   [(selection)]="selectedMessages"
   selectionMode="multiple">
```

I need to programmatically select the row the user just clicked on.  I figured I would just push a new object to `selectedMessages` in the click, but it does not work.  The object is pushed, but nothing remains selected.

I need to handle the right-click.  The row is defined as:

```html
<tr (contextmenu)="clickMessage(message)">
```

The event is handled with:

```js
clickMessage(mail: MailboxItem): void {
    this.selectedMessages.push(mail);
}
```

The member is initialized to empty:

```js
selectedMessages: MailboxItem[] = [];
```

My event fires properly, the object goes from empty (`[]`) to having one `MailboxItem` in it, but no table rows are selected.

Comment: I don't understand the vote to close for "Needs Debugging Details".  What more can I provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Angular change detection only occurs when the array bound to `[(selection)]` is modified.

The solution is to re-assign to the array itself which will trigger change detection and properly select the row:

```
this.selectedMessages = [...this.selectedMessages, mail];
```

In my use-case we want to de-select all rows except the one being right-clicked on, so it is simply:

```
this.selectedMessages = [ mail ];
```

Comment: `this.selectedMessages = [...this.selectedMessages, mail];` would be a better synthax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I can't test this now, but I guess you should put the **id** of your MailboxItem object as **"dataKey"** in your table.

For instance, if your mail rows are getting value from an array like this:

```
mailsArray: MailboxItem[]  =
[ 
 { 
   myId=1; 
   from="Patrick"; 
   message="Blah,blah,bla..";
 },
 { 
   myId=2; 
   from="Swaiczwe"; 
   message="Lorem blahblah etceterabla..";
 }
];
```

then your table should had a dataKey attibute like this:

```
<p-table
   [(selection)]="selectedMessages"
   selectionMode="multiple"
   [value]="mailsArray"
   dataKey="myId"
>
```

And finally, your method clickMessage() should be like this:

```
clickMessage(mail: MailboxItem): void {
    this.selectedMessages.push(mail.myID);
}
```

You should put also something similar to this in yours header and body templates (sorry, but you didn't show how you have it, so it's approximate):

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
   <tr [pSelectableRow]="mail">
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>Message</th>
   </tr>
</ng-template>

<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-mail  let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
            <tr [pSelectableRow]="mail" [pSelectableRowIndex]="rowIndex">
                <td>{{mail.myId}}</td>
                <td>{{mail.from}}</td>
                <td>{{mail.message}}</td>
            </tr>
</ng-template>
```

P.S: Also try changing

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
   <tr [pSelectableRow]="mail">
```

just to a 'simple' , like this:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
   <tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but it doesn't work using `dataKey`.  I also can't do `<tr [pSelectableRow]="mail">` in the header template because `mail` is a `let-mail` in the body, it is not available in the header.

Comment: Sorry, my last part of the answer didn't show. I've edited now.